# Specify response data type

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, angular-services, angular-httpclient

I'm calling an api from Angular 10 app and is executing everthing ok! But the response is like an error, I'm getting this message:

> "Http failure during parsing for https://APIurl"

I was searching for a solution and now I know that is because the response from the api, I'm getting the following response as plain text:

> Operation successfully.

So my question is what can I do in my Angular app to specifiy that I'm expecting text instead of json.

This is my service code:

```
public create = (route: string, body: any) => {
    return this.http.post(this.createCompleteRoute(route, this.envUrl.urlAddress), body, this.generateHeaders());
}

private generateHeaders = () => {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
    }
}
```

I tried removing the Content-Type but was no possible because the api is expecting the values FromBody.

Answer (score 0):

maybe changing your header to something like this

```
var headers = new Headers({
    "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
    "Accept": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
});
```

Comment: I changed to  var headers = new Headers({
      "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
      "Accept": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
    });
    return headers; but now it says that there is no matching overload in my http.post call

Comment: try it exact like this
public create = (route: string, body: any) => {
    return this.http.post(this.createCompleteRoute(route, this.envUrl.urlAddress), body, this.generateHeaders());
}

private generateHeaders = () => {
    return {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'text/plain; charset=utf-8'})
    }
}

or change 'text/plain; charset=utf-8' by only 'text/plain'